# How to parse this JSON file using JavaScript/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to parse the below json.If I try to get the value as in
the below code is showing undefined.

Is there is any way I can parse the json in which key as the space?

```
 {
        "Trasport Fee":{
        "KARNATAKA":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES":{
        "amount":4000
        }
        }
        },
        "ANDRA":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES​":{
        "amount":100
        }
        }
        },
        "MP":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES​":{
        "amount":600
        }
        }
        },
        "MAHARASHTRA":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES​":{
        "amount":600
        }
        }
        }
        }
    }
      var promise=feeService.getTraspotaionFee();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.charge=data;
            console.log($scope.charge.data["Trasport Fee"]["KARNATAKA"]["ALL_DISTRICT"]["amount"]);

        });
```

Comment: `Transpotion Fee` -> `Transport Fee`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
        "Trasport Fee":{
        "KARNATAKA":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES":{
        "amount":4000
        }
        }
        },
        "ANDRA":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES​":{
        "amount":100
        }
        }
        },
        "MP":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES​":{
        "amount":600
        }
        }
        },
        "MAHARASHTRA":{
        "ALL_DISTRICT":{
        "ALL_PLACES​":{
        "amount":600
        }
        }
        }
        }

      var promise=feeService.getTraspotaionFee();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.charge=data;
            console.log($scope.charge.data["Trasport Fee"]["KARNATAKA"]["ALL_DISTRICT"]["ALL_PLACES"]["amount"]);

        });
```

your key is transport fee not transforation.You missed ALL_PLACES before amount

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid a curly bracket is missing at the end.
Use a JSON Validator, thats what I do first if there are problems with "JSON" data.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/  <-- nice validator

Answer (score 0):

```
    var promise=feeService.getTraspotaionFee();
        promise.then(function(data){
            $scope.charge=data;

//changes here
            console.log($scope.charge.data[Object.keys($scope.charge.data)[0]]["KARNATAKA"]["ALL_DISTRICT"]["ALL_PLACES"]["amount"]);

        });
```

Change above code and use

Comment: angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ALL_DISTRICT' of undefined
    at angularApp.js:32
    at angular.js:16170
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17444)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:17257)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17552)
    at l (angular.js:11697)
    at K (angular.js:11903)
    at XMLHttpRequest.y.onload (angular.js:11836)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
console.log($scope.charge.data["Trasport Fee"]["KARNATAKA"]["ALL_DISTRICT"]["ALL_PLACES"]["amount"]);
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I also fixed your JSON (missing brackets):

```
{
   "Trasport Fee":{
      "KARNATAKA":{
         "ALL_DISTRICT":{
            "ALL_PLACES":{
               "amount":4000
            }
         }
      },
      "ANDRA":{
         "ALL_DISTRICT":{
            "ALL_PLACES​":{
               "amount":100
            }
         }
      },
      "MP":{
         "ALL_DISTRICT":{
            "ALL_PLACES​":{
               "amount":600
            }
         }
      },
      "MAHARASHTRA":{
         "ALL_DISTRICT":{
            "ALL_PLACES​":{
               "amount":600
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**observation :**

- Issue is not with the spaces in key. you are accessing the value in correct way only.
- You got undefined because you are trying to accessing the `amount` property inside `ALL_DISTRICT` object which is not available.

**Try this :**

```
$scope.charge.data["Trasport Fee"]["KARNATAKA"]["ALL_DISTRICT"]["ALL_PLACES"]["amount"]
```

**DEMO**

```js
var data = {
 "Trasport Fee": {
  "KARNATAKA": {
   "ALL_DISTRICT": {
    "ALL_PLACES": {
     "amount": 4000
    }
   }
  },
  "ANDRA": {
   "ALL_DISTRICT": {
    "ALL_PLACES": {
     "amount": 100
    }
   }
  },
  "MP": {
   "ALL_DISTRICT": {
    "ALL_PLACES": {
     "amount": 600
    }
   }
  },
  "MAHARASHTRA": {
   "ALL_DISTRICT": {
    "ALL_PLACES": {
     "amount": 600
    }
   }
  }
 }
};

console.log(data["Trasport Fee"]["KARNATAKA"]["ALL_DISTRICT"]["ALL_PLACES"]["amount"]);
```

Comment: There was the bug in JSON code.Most of the JSON editor shows that it is valid JSON when I rewrote the JSON  now it working perfectly now.

Comment: You got undefined because you are trying to accessing the amount property inside ALL_DISTRICT object which is not available